# With an express app, how to use my schema data in css/stylus?

Tags: css, node.js, express, pug, stylus

I'm trying to create a themes for my express app and i'm trying to do something that i'm not sure is possible. I need some expert advice on ways or methods to do this.

This is my schema...

```
var colorSchema = new Schema({
    primaryColor: {
        type: String
    },
    secondaryColor: {
        type: String
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Color', colorSchema);
```

Let's say i've entered hex colors into primaryColor and secondaryColor when I create a new schema. How can I parse **color.primaryColor** as a value in my css or stylus like you do in jade?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to first pass the data to Jade through render in Express:

```
// Default both to white
res.render('template_name', {
  primaryColor: color.primaryColor || '#FFF',
  secondaryColor: color.secondaryColor || '#FFF',
  someOtherVar: 'foo'
});
```

Then, in your Jade template:

```
style(type='text/css')
  | .primary-color-bg { background-color: #{primaryColor}; }
  | .secondary-color-bg { background-color: #{secondaryColor}; }
```

You can then apply `primary-color-bg` and `secondary-color-bg` classes to any DOM elements you want to set the background of. You can replicate for `color`, `border`, etc. attributes.

Comment: That works well enough for what I want. But what If I wanted to do something more complex with colors. Like using lighten(#000, 30%) or darken(#000, 30%) functions in stylus or scss.

Answer (score 0):

[*Stylus* actually has a JavaScript API](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/js.html) that allows you to render  even arbitrary strings of Stylus code.

```
stylus = require('stylus');

variable = '#fff';

stylus.render(
  "\n.thing" +
  "\n  color: " + variable + "\n",
  console.log);
```

This is a pretty dumb example, but it gets the point of freedom you have. That API also allows for more "composable" compile-function definition, that lets you expose JS values (via `.define`) into Stylus.

```
stylus(str)
  .set('filename', 'nesting.css')
  .define('whatever', '#fff')
  .render(console.log);
```